# Android Twitter Kit get user email

Tags: android, twitter

I have integrated Twitter Kit in my android app to allow user "Sign in with twitter".

Every thing works good however I am unable to get user email address.

To get email address of user I am doing the following:

```
User user = Twitter.getApiClient().getAccountService().verifyCredentials(true, false);
Log.d(TWITTER_LOGIN, "name : " + user.name);
Log.d(TWITTER_LOGIN, "email: " + user.email);
Log.d(TWITTER_LOGIN, "image: " + user.profileImageUrl);
```

Logcat is as follows:

```
03-16 15:46:52.964  12839-13982/com.blackfoxweb.colaxi D/TWITTER_LOGIN﹕ name : A.S.Parmar
03-16 15:46:52.964  12839-13982/com.blackfoxweb.colaxi D/TWITTER_LOGIN﹕ email: null
03-16 15:46:52.964  12839-13982/com.blackfoxweb.colaxi D/TWITTER_LOGIN﹕ image: http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3450482402/77de4f868f3037baf1e6187ba2d33ca0.jpeg
```

I can get the name and image url of user through

```
user.name
```

and

```
user.profileImageUrl
```

But I am getting null in

```
user.email
```

Is it the right way to get email address? Or am I missing something?
Please tell if more information is required to understand my question.

Update:
Tried to access email as shown [here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email). But getting an exception as:

```
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException: Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.
```

Comment: As per documented in twitter's site -> if someone signed up for Twitter with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.Check this out

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email

Comment: Tried to log in with twitter account signed up using email but no luck.. :(

Comment: so what is the solution if a user did not sign up with email, just tell them?

Comment: did you solved the issue